# How to fix issues with number position for Joomla site in Chrome/IE and Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, joomla

I have come across a few issues on a Joomla site that I have built using Joomla 3.5.1. I have written CSS to ensure that the site is responsive and this all works fine.

The problem I have is that the site's header shows up different in the following browsers and versions:

Firefox 48.0.2 (this shows up fine)
Chrome 52.0 (telephone number out of place)
Internet Explorer 10 (telephone number and search bar out of place)

I am not sure how I can target for the site to work correctly in Chrome so therefore not sure how I fix this in my css. I was under the impression the site would show up the same in all browsers like Chrome, Firefox and it would only be Internet Explorer where I can target different styles, but there is something thats not quite right.

The site's URL is: http://www.leicesterbakery.co.uk

I would appreciate it if somebody could give me some advice on how i can fix this, as I have tried the inspect element in Chrome but can't pinpoint how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

FF and Chrome render fonts in different way, there is always 1-2px different.  You can try to use a bit smaller font, or make parent object a bit wider - try to reduce padding for phone icon - you will see this will also help in Chrome.

About IE - think it is issue with floats. i'm not sure how to fix it,
Maybe try not to use so big padding-left for Phone icon. think better solution for icon can be position: absolute;

Comment: Thanks Arek, will have a look at your suggestions.